# heroku postgres ETIMEDOUT when conencting through localhost

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have a website which uses the free tier of heroku postgres I was running it on localhost and it was working just fine till today no changes were made to the code and the database url and everything is just fine

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 3.224.164.189:5432
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1246:16) {
  errno: -4039,
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '3.224.164.189',
  port: 5432
}
```

This is the error which I get and this error is only shown on localhost, when the same code is deployed to heroku, it works just fine
Also, one thing which I've noticed is that it works just fine when I use my mobile network and this issue only occurs when I use my ethernet connection.

Can Someone help me out with this sticky situation?

Comment: What do you mean with "on localhost"?  what was on localhost, the database? the web server/app server? the web browswer? all of them?

Comment: the expressJS server listening on port 8000
Express is being used to serve files and routing
Also, the database is hosted on heroku as mentioned